# Running emulator leads to endless download

Tags: react-native

I created a new project with the console command `react-native init myApp --template react-native-template-typescript`.

After that, I opened the project folder in `vs code` and ran the commands in two terminals.

Terminal 1 logs

```
user1@ps:~/documents/projects/myApp$ npx react-native start
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /home/user1/documents/projects/myApp 

Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Terminal 2 logs

```
user1@ps:~/documents/projects/myApp$ npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [10m 45s]
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:installDebug
> IDLE
```

After which there is an eternal download.

I opened the folder for android in `android studio` and launched the project, it worked successfully and started.

What is my problem that I cannot start the project with the `npx react-native run-android`command in `vs code`?

What other information should I add to solve my problem?

Comment: Why don't you use your computer's terminal?

Comment: @Ian Vasco It’s more convenient for me to work in the open terminal `vs code`. But I tried to run the application in bash and the result is the same

Comment: What about using this flag `--no-jetifier`

Comment: @Ian Vasco The same behavior, the emulator opens and there is an eternal download at the stage: `app: installDebug`